# Checkbox - What is checked? Jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have this code:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="11">
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="10">

<div id="log"></div>

$("input").click(function() {
  $("#log").html( $(":checked").val() + " is checked!" );
});
```

If I start by checking the first checkbox, then the next, it will add: 11 is checked.

**How can I do so, it takes ALL submitted checkbox values** - like:
11,10, is checked.

And is it possible to extract those values with php so it looks like this:
10
11
Without the ","

UPDATE:

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function() {
    var kolort = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').val(); 
    var output = $(this).text() + ", " + kolort;

  /*
  $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(index) {
    output += $(this).text() + ", ";
  });*/

  alert(output + "is checked!");
});
```

I now have this. ALthough, it just prints out ONE of the values and not both. **How can I do so it take values from EACH input?**

Comment: why dont you give seperate id for check boxes!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `.each()` API:

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function() {
  var output = '';

  $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(index) {
    output += $(this).val() + ", ";
  });

  alert(output + "is checked!");
});
```

Test page: http://pastebin.com/LVuLUthB

As for removing the commas, there will be no commas when processing in PHP. Checkboxes are sent as an array. What you want to do is:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="11">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="10">
```

And then in the PHP:

```
echo implode(', ', $_POST['checkbox']) . ' are checked!';
```

Comment: This code:

`$('input[type="submit"]').click(function() {
  var output = '';

  $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(index) {
    output += $(this).text() + ", ";
  }

  alert(output + "is checked!");
});
`
Gives me unexpected token ) error.

Comment: sorry, idiotic syntax error - forgot to close brackets for each. Updated code.

Comment: Works now. Although, it just says ", is checked". It does not gives the values from the checkboxes.

Comment: ahhhh I clearly need more coffee. Okay, I've updated & tested the code and it should work now.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Two controls cannot have the same ID.**
2. Subject to fixing #1, it is easy to use `.val()` and/or to treat the returned jQuery collection as an ordered sequence. Since #1 is fixed this will require a selector based on type or name, etc.
3. The code in the post does not interact with PHP. Consider revising the question/code. Note that `<input type="checkbox" name="choice[]">` (note the name) might be useful for handling on the server as a collection.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [jQuery `.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/). The following will iterate through all checked checkboxes. As @zod states in his comment, **IDs are unique**, use a class instead.

```
$("input").click(function() {
    $(":checked").each(function() {
         $("#log").html($(this).val() + " is checked!");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/javascript-15/get-value-checkbox-checked-jquery-583619.html

```
$(function(){
  $('#btnClick').click(function(){
    var val = [];
    $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
      val[i] = $(this).val();
    });
  });
});
```

and refer this too

http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

Answer (score 0):

`.val()` will always return the value of the first matched element: http://api.jquery.com/val/

Try this:

```
$("input").click(function() {
    $(":checked").each(function() {
        $("#log").html( this.val() + " is checked!" );
    })
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Like @zod said, you will need different ids on your checkboxes. In addition, you will need a loop to process all the checkboxes. Try this:

`var total = "";
$(":checked").each(function(){ if(total != "") total = total + ","; total = total + $(this).val(); });
$("#log").html(total + " is checked!");`